# What was the first language to offer "full" structured programming support?

Tags: history

In the same vein as [this question about conditionals](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390578/what-was-the-first-language-to-use-conditional-keywords), I am interested in the first time a language provided functionality we assume as a given for modern programming languages. The question is when a programming language fully embraced structured programming by providing all 4 control structures (sequence, selection, iteration & recursion).

Now, "sequence" seems like a given, but selection, iteration & recursion also need to be provided. As far as I can see that means

- conditional keywords (e.g. `if...then`)
- loop keywords (`while`, `for` etc.)
- functions which are able to call themselves

For the keywords, they should be dedicated keywords for the purpose mentioned here, opposed to "things that can also be used that way".

When was a programmer first able to make use of all 4 control structures in a language?

Comment: My memory doesn't go back far enough to name a particular language, but I expect the first higher-level (i.e. non-assembly) languages to fit the bill. Assembly has all of them except the loop keywords.

Comment: ALGOL 58 was the first widely-known language. You could start there and work your way backwards.

Comment: "Dedicated keywords"? Other than that, Lisp would be the answer. (Lisp doesn't need keywords, dedicated or otherwise.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- By [FLOW-MATIC](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/historydisplays/FourthFloor/ReportsAndViewer/Reports/Flowmatic.pdf) (1955) there are conditional jumps to labels (`IF ... GO TO ...`).
- Lisp was conceived at some point between 1956 and 1958. And would have been influenced by FORTRAN. See [Early LISP History](https://web.archive.org/web/20050405213907/http://www8.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/html/lisp/histlit1.html). The first implementation was completed in 1959. The design for Lisp was published on McCarthy's paper ["Recursive Functions of Symbolic Expressions and Their Computation by Machine"](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html) (1960) which had conditionals and recursion.
- FORTRAN I (1957) had conditionals and introduced loops (`DO`). It won't have recursion until FORTRAN 77 (1977).
- [ALGOL 58](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/report/Algol58_preliminary_report_CACM.pdf/) (1958) had conditionals (`if`, `switch`), loops (`for`, `do`) and recursion.

See also:

- [Timeline of programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages)
- [Programming Loops vs Recursion - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXNhEYqFo0o) (video)
- [How recursion got into programming: a tale of intrigue, betrayal, and advanced programming-language semantics](https://vanemden.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/how-recursion-got-into-programming-a-comedy-of-errors-3/)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the first three are pioneers for the respective _parts_ and ALGOL 58 was the first to provide _the whole set_ in 1958?

Comment: @R.Schmitz well, assembler had conditional jump instructions since the beginning, not sure if you would count that. And of course people would do loops using that. I do not know if you want a recursion keyword... if you want that, then FORTRAN 77 is the first, you write `recursive subroutine` when declaring.

Comment: Standard Fortran 77 did not include recursion, though most real-world "Fortran 77" compilers had a non-standard way to do it. The first Fortran standard to permit recursion was Fortran 90.

Comment: I would consider Algol the first structured language. Assembly languages can emulate structured languages but they're not inherently structured.

Comment: @TimLocke "_Assembly languages can emulate structured languages but they're not inherently structured._" Hitting the nail on the head with that; I did not manage to put that into words as well as you.

Comment: @TimLocke That is not inherently (SCNR) true. Assembler can as well be structured and have that feature controlled at compile time - like any other structured language. I used that for most of my professional life.

Comment: @Raffzahn, that is not an inherent feature of assembly language but of an assembler.

Comment: @TimLocke Could it be that you're confusing the instruction set of a machine with the assembly language available to program it? These are close related, but quite different items. Assembler on the other hand is just the program to translate assembly language into instructions. Given, these words are often used interchangeable, but if we want a serious base we need to stay clear.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree my wording is confusing. However, that is no typo. The first implementation was in 1959 (The very first in May, the first complete one in June). And the paper was published in April of 1960. For what I was able to find, it was conceived at some point between 1956 and 1958, but I don't know much of that timeline. I'll edit the answer. Edit: updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of misconceptions in this one:

1. Recursion is just another kind of iteration. It was in fact the *only* iteration mechanism provided in early versions of Lisp. Any use of recursion can be transformed into standard looping iteration (although many of them require use of a stack as well). Recursion can be viewed as kind of a hack to be able to leverage the program stack for your stack usage while iterating (in languages that use a program stack). Likewise early Lisp demonstrated that its possible (although not always convenient) to use recursion for all your iteration needs.
2. I have never before heard that support for recursion is required for a language to be considered a "structured language". Really all that is required is that the language be Turing complete without relying on "unstructured" branch statements (aka: GOTOs)

Now with all these caveats, most of the early "Structured Programming" developers were also at the same time involved in the development and use of [ALGOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL). This includes most prominently Dijkstra, who was the leading light in both the Structured Programming movement and developed the first ALGOL 60 compiler. Hoare and Dahl were also very involved in the development of both.

The other major languages that were extant at the time were COBOL and FORTRAN. Early FORTRAN in particular made extensive use of GOTOs, along with data overlays that are essentially the data equivalent of GOTOS, and thus a large amount of the development of ALGOL was in reaction to FORTRAN. So if you are looking for the early standard-bearer for the paradigm, ALGOL is probably your language.

Comment: `Recursion is just another kind of iteration.` -- This whole paragraph kind of begs the question.  Yes, recursion and iteration are interchangeable.  Would you want to, though?

Comment: `Really all that is required is that the language be Turing complete...`  Same thing.  Brainfuck is interesting from an intellectual perspective, but nobody seriously considers writing real programs in it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Tons of reasons why you might want to. [Compilers routinely do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240539/what-is-tail-recursion-elimination) as an optimization. Early LISP users with no other looping mechanism also did it routinely the other way. I've personally implemented algorithms both ways, and picked the one that looked easier to read/maintain.

Comment: Well, yes.  But none of that has much to do with whether a language can be defined as having "full structured programming support," unless you can offer more particulars.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Well, yes, because that term is nonsense, and thus there's no such thing. I did put a paragraph at the end relating it to the languages that were current at the time. That's really the best that can be legitimately done with the question that was asked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Rereading the other answers and comments here, it seems like I'm essentially in agreement with Tim Locke, but with a longform explanation as to why.

Comment: The first Lisp implementation (eventually named LISP 1.5) had `PROG` and `GO`, which provided a lexically-scoped label/goto mechanism; it was somewhat better than FORTRAN, since symbolic labels could be used. See section V of the LISP 1.5 Programmer's Manual. According to McCarthy's "History of Lisp", "the idea of having sequential programs in LISP antedates that of having recursive function definition." (The `prog` and `go` operators still exist in Common Lisp, although `prog` is now defined to be a macro.)

Comment: @texdr.aft - Goto's are a building block that can be used to implement iteration (among many other things) rather than an actual iteration mechanisim themselves, but otherwise this point seems quite fair.

Answer (score 4):

This is a copy-paste of my answer to the other question. R. Schmitz said I could do it though.

If we are talking about a block structured conditional like

```
if condition
    some arbitrary sequence of statements including perhaps nested ifs
else 
    some other arbitrary sequence of statements including perhaps nested ifs
```

rather than just `if ... goto some label` which is no different to a conditional branch, then two early contenders would be:

- Lisp (1958) which has an `if` and `cond` function. I think `cond`predates `if`. When I learned Lisp in the 1980's I'm fairly sure that `if` wasn't there. Lisp also had recursion, which means it had iteration by definition.
- Algol 60 (1960) which has the structured `if` inherited by most modern imperative languages. Also `while` and `for` loops and recursion.

Early versions of FORTRAN and COBOL did not have structured `if` statements as far as I know or recursion.